# How to pass rewritten url to fcgi in lighttpd

Tags: fastcgi, redmine, lighttpd

I have a redmine instance that runs in the `/redmine` sub-uri. This is fully working and I can retrieve `/redmine/robots.txt` without fault.

Adding

```
url.rewrite = ( "^/robots\.txt$" => "/redmine/robots.txt" )
```

still gives a 404 error when trying to retrieve /robots.txt.

1. The request in `error.log` appears identical to GETting /redmine/robots.txt after an initial block changing the url if I turn on `debug.log-request-handling = "enable"`
2. Using url.rewrite-once does not seem to make a difference.
3. The request never shows up in redmine `production.log`.

So my question is what I might be missing?

Comment: Just guessing here but, do the special chars in the regex need to be escaped? Like `^\/robots\.txt$`

Comment: Why do you think that the request for a static file would show up in `production.log` from redmine instead of in the lighttpd access log (if you have one configured)?

Comment: That's not a static file: redmine/robots.txt is generated dynamically by redmine to include some specific links (that lead to navigation inconsequential for search). Why the rewritten request never makes it to the FCGI redmine instance kind of is the question here.

Comment: @Simone you are right, the backslash is there in the file, only missing in the question article. I'll add it back right now.

Comment: "The request in error.log appears identical to GETting /redmine/robots.txt after an initial block changing the url if I turn on `debug.log-request-handling = "enable"`"  If the request is identical after the rewrite, the behavior should be, too.  Try to `strace` the lighttpd executable when you make the request and see if that yields any clues.  (You can post the log to lighttpd forums at https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/boards)  FYI: the '/' does not need to be escaped in a regex (but no harm in doing so).  A literal '.' does need to be escaped to be treated as a literal '.'